# Need to pad zeros left and right for a string value according to decimal format

Tags: sql, sql-server

So if I have a data (varchar) like say `10.1`

I need the value as `0000101000000`.

means (000010) whole number and (1000000) decimal value.

Its a 13 character string ,numbers coming before decimal point should be in first 6 characters and numbers coming after decimal point should be in last 7 characters

Comment: SQL Server does not use PIC formats.  Something is wrong with your question.

Comment: Forget about PIC Format . i just want to separate whole number and decimal.

Comment: @Bharath based on what you have to convert? 10 can be written as 010,0010 and so on.. Please provide more information

Comment: @AswaniMadhavan Its a 13 character string ,numbers coming before decimal point should be in first 6 characters and numbers coming after decimal point should be in last 7 characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

declare @var varchar(20) = '10000.112'

SELECT FORMAT (FLOOR(@var), '000000') + left((PARSENAME(@var,1)) + replicate('0',7),7)

Answer (score 4):

Maybe..?

```
DECLARE @d decimal(13,7) = 10.1;

SELECT RIGHT('0000000000000' + CONVERT(varchar(13),CONVERT(bigint,(@d * 10000000))),13);
```

Using my crystal ball here though.

*Edit: As, for some reason, the OP is storing a `decimal` as a `varchar` (this is a really bad bad idea on it's own), I have added further logic to attempt to convert the value to a `decimal` first.*

*As experience has taught many of us, give a user a non-numeric column to store a numeric value in and they're more than happily store a non-numeric value in it, so i have used `TRY_CONVERT` and assumed you are using SQL Server 2012+:*

```
DECLARE @d varchar(13) = 10.1;

SELECT RIGHT('0000000000000' + CONVERT(varchar(13),CONVERT(bigint,(TRY_CONVERT(decimal(13,7),@d) * 10000000))),13);
```

Comment: Declared variable @d should be varchar

Comment: @Bharath Why is that not in your question then?

Comment: The better question is, why are you storing numbers as a `varchar` @Bharath..?

Comment: yup. sorry, i have added.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT REPLICATE('0',6-LEN(SUBSTRING(CAST([data] AS VARCHAR), 1, 
       CHARINDEX('.',CAST([data] AS VARCHAR)) -1)))+SUBSTRING(CAST([data] AS VARCHAR), 1, 
       CHARINDEX('.',CAST([data] AS VARCHAR)) -1)+
       SUBSTRING(CAST([data] AS VARCHAR), CHARINDEX('.',CAST([data] AS VARCHAR)) + 1, 
       LEN(CAST([data] AS VARCHAR)))+REPLICATE('0',7-LEN(SUBSTRING(CAST([data] AS VARCHAR), CHARINDEX('.',CAST([data] AS VARCHAR)) + 1, 
       LEN(CAST([data] AS VARCHAR))))) AS Whole
       FROM Table1
```

**Output**

```
Whole
0000101000000
```

**Demo**

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8649d/16

Answer (score 1):

You can use some math and string operations to do it like below

<kbd>**[see live demo](http://rextester.com/NATT52380)**</kbd>

```
declare @var decimal(10,4)

set @var=10.1

select @var, 
right(cast(cast(( floor(@var)+  power(10,7)) as int) as varchar(13)),6)
    +
cast(cast(((@var- floor(@var)) * power(10,7)) as int) as varchar(13))
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a fair amount of string manipulation to be done here. I'll step through what I did.

I used a variable for the base number so I could verify different results:

```
declare @n decimal(9,3) = 10.1
```

You need 6 spaces left of the decimal and 7 spaces to the right, so I'm doing all the manipulation on a VARCHAR(13). I didn't create a new variable as a VARCHAR because I'm assuming you want to be able to do this conversion in line on the fly, so I'm using that CAST over and over again.

Start by finding the decimal place.

```
SELECT CHARINDEX('.',CAST(@n as VARCHAR(13)))
```

In the sample number, that's a 3, but it could obviously change.

Now, get the portion of the number to the left of the decimal place.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(CAST(@n as VARCHAR(13)),1,CHARINDEX('.',CAST(@n as VARCHAR(13)))-1)
```

Then get the portion to the right of the decimal.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(CAST(@n as VARCHAR(13)),CHARINDEX('.',CAST(@n as VARCHAR(13)))+1,LEN(CAST(@n as VARCHAR(13))))
```

Pad the leading zeroes. Put 6 on, concatenate, and take a RIGHT 6. Accounts for no digits to the left of the decimal.

```
SELECT RIGHT(REPLICATE(0,6) + SUBSTRING(CAST(@n as VARCHAR(13)),1,CHARINDEX('.',CAST(@n as VARCHAR(13)))-1), 6)
```

Pad the trailing zeroes. Same idea, but in the other direction.

```
SELECT LEFT(SUBSTRING(CAST(@n as VARCHAR(13)),CHARINDEX('.',CAST(@n as VARCHAR(13)))+1,LEN(CAST(@n as VARCHAR(13)))) + REPLICATE(0,7),7)
```

Then put it all together.

```
SELECT RIGHT(REPLICATE(0,6) + SUBSTRING(CAST(@n as VARCHAR(13)),1,CHARINDEX('.',CAST(@n as VARCHAR(13)))-1), 6) 
+ 
LEFT(SUBSTRING(CAST(@n as VARCHAR(13)),CHARINDEX('.',CAST(@n as VARCHAR(13)))+1,LEN(CAST(@n as VARCHAR(13)))) + REPLICATE(0,7),7)
```

Results.

```
0000101000000
```